# File Not Found: Run as Administrator

Tags: windows

I have a shortcut:
C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe -jar -Xmx2048m MyJar.jar

It runs fine and perfect without administrator rights...

But when I use "Run as Administrator", it comes back with "Unable to access jarfile MyJar.jar".

Both the shortcut and the .jar are on the Desktop.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `MyJar.jar` situated? Where does the administrator console run?

Comment: Both the shortcut and the .jar file are on My Desktop.

Comment: You may need to put the full file path for `MyJar.jar`

Comment: Same problem, just with full filepath.

Comment: It works fine if I `cd` to the path it's in under an admin cmd

Comment: You may need to put the file path between `"` then!